# What's the meaning of this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, syntax

What operation is being done to the `arr[i], arr[i+1]` in the second line:

```
if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
   arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
   sorted = false
end
```

Comment: This looks like part of someone's implementation of [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What operation is being done to the arr[i], arr[i+1] in the second line.

`arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]` means value swapping to sort the array.

```
arr = [3,2]
i = 0
arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
arr # => [2,3]
```

> What's this type of ternary called?

This is called [**`parallel`**](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_Expressions_Parallel_Assignment.html) assignment,not *ternary*.

Comment: It's not a *ternary* though. That refers specifically to the `x ? y : z` inline-if equivalent.

Comment: @tadman I think OP called by mistake that assignment as ternary.. :)

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  I see the swap now.  the ith value becomes the i+1th value. and vice verse.  wow. all done automagically without using a temp variable.